# Query in MS Access returns "#Funktion!"

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have to write a subquery to allow for easier sorting in an old access database.

What i have so far:

```
Select Anschluss,
       AnschlussOhnePunkt,
       switch(
           IsNumeric(LEFT(AnschlussOhnePunkt,1)) = True, 
           len(AnschlussOhnePunkt), IsNumeric(LEFT(AnschlussOhnePunkt,1)) = False, 9999) as ordnung
from (
    select Anschluss, 
           switch(isnull(Anschluss), Anschluss,
           instr(Anschluss, '.') = 0, Anschluss, 
           instr(Anschluss, '.') = 1, left(Anschluss, instr(Anschluss, '.')-1)) as AnschlussOhnePunkt
    from T_Anschluss
)
```

Basically the subquery is supposed to return "Anschluss" and if it contains a dot it should remove that and return it as "AnschlussOhnePunkt".

So 2.1 should become 2 etc.

But for some reason "AnschlussOhnePunkt" returns "#Funktion!" and I have no idea or explanation why.
Can someone explain why it comes or how to solve this problem?

- Rewriting the Query
- Casting to string value
- Using only the subquery alone

None of it solved the problem and did apparently nothing.

Comment: Do you perhaps have a function `AnschlussOhnePunkt` somewhere in your code? Do a global search in the VBA editor.

Comment: No I do not have such a function anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`left(Anschluss, instr(Anschluss, '.')-1)` is a problematic statement, since if `instr(Anschluss)` is 0, that's a `Left(Anschluss, -1)` and the second argument of `Left` needs to be 0 or positive.

You may think this can never occur, since the `Switch` breaks earlier, but all arguments to a `Switch` are always evaluated, regardless if an earlier option is returned.

This means we have to escape that case with an `IIF`:

```sql
Left(
   Anschluss,
   InStr(Anschluss, '.') - 
      Iif(InStr(Anschluss, '.') > 0, 1, 0) 
)
```

Note that this statement is predicated on `instr(Anschluss, '.') = 1` so it doesn't really make sense. I assume you'd want `instr(Anschluss, '.') > 0` to detect if there's a dot somewhere in the string, not if there's a dot at the first position in the string.

Comment: I tinkered around with your input and yes, the `=1` check was a mistake from my side, but still wasn't the whole solution.
I now changed it to "iif" statements instead of switch and now I get proper results.